# What is the meaning of “calling in” in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> Mavis Wanczyk won the second-largest lottery prize in U.S. history Wednesday, a $758 million Powerball jackpot that she celebrated by **calling in** newly rich, telling her longtime employer that she would not be coming in to work.

I can't figure out what it means in this context.

Comment: Note that ***newly rich*** is an adverbial phrase, equivalent to ***as a "newly-rich" employee*** (who by implication no longer wants to go to work, since she doesn't need the money any more).

Comment: Note that the way ***newly rich*** is used there is as a stylised/literary "device".  It's highly unlikely any native speaker would ever actually say *When I won the lottery I called in newly rich and told the boss exactly where he could stick his lousy job* in a real-word spoken context..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Call in](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/license/amp/dictionary/british/call-in_1)** (see no. 5) means to communicate via telephone, typically with some larger unit like one's place of work.

So in plain text,

> Mavis W. telephoned her employer to tell him that she wouldn't come to work.

---

Note that **[call in](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/license/amp/dictionary/british/call-in_1)** (see no.1) may also mean to visit briefly, but the context here makes that interpretation very unlikely - she would not stop by to say that she won't come.

Comment: In the US "call in" in a work context has a specific meaning of "let your boss know you won't be coming into work". For example, "I've got a terrible migraine. I think I will call in to work today."

Comment: @ColleenV which I always understood as "call in [sick]".

Comment: Well in this context instead of "sick", Mavis is calling in "newly rich" :)  You can substitute other words for "sick".  For example, "I think I'm going to call-in 'underpaid' today..."

Comment: A minor point: it would be more idiomatic to say "she wouldn't *be coming in* to work".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo true, I omitted the "in" on purpose because I didn't want to use the same pattern of "in" = "to work/the office"

Comment: @Stephie: Yes, but it would be more idiomatic not to worry about the doubling of **in** :)    *She called in to say she wouldn't be coming in.*  In avoiding a non-problem you create a little one.